# Can Mummified Hand's effect be wasted on a card that already costs 0 energy?

Tags: slay-the-spire

The description for Mummified Hand says

> Whenever you play a Power, a random card in your hand costs 0 for the turn.

Is it possible for Mummified Hand's effect to be wasted by targeting a card that already costs 0 energy like Miracle or Consecrate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Slay the Spire Wiki](https://slay-the-spire.fandom.com/wiki/Mummified_Hand), no.

> **As with other effects that reduce the cost of a random card, Mummified Hand will never "waste" itself by targeting a card that already costs 0.** This includes skills affected by Corruption, and holds true even when it triggers from playing Corruption itself; the power's effect is applied before Mummified Hand.

This supports my anecdotal experience, as I have not seen Mummified Hand affect a 0 cost card while playing.